# Using QnA Maker generateAnswer API, getting Response as Unable to translate bytes [A0] at index 35 from specified code page to Unicode

Tags: python-3.x, api, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

Been using generateAnswer API for QnA Service of Microsoft. As a Reference exact code with keys manipulation been used from link: [Text]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/get-answer-from-knowledge-base-python.
Have used same structure as its been mentioned in reference attached and its working for more than 95 percent of questions. But for few questions i am getting response saying Bad Argument
 **{'error': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'Unable to translate bytes [A0] at index 35 from specified code page to Unicode.'}}**
Does any body having any clue why this is hapening and could help me out. I thought may be this is because of header section whats being sent with post request, so i updated header content as following but no luck.

```
header = {
            'Authorization': 'EndpointKey ' + end_point_key,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8'
        }
```

Does any body have any idea what could be the issue here and how could i solve this. i am using **python >3.0 here**. Appreciate it!